# How to use a Vue Component (.udm.js) in a basic Vue html file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, github-pages

I built a `Vue component` that was packaged with `"build-bundle": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name my-component ./src/myComponent.vue"`. In the `dist` folder I have:

- demo.html
- my-component.common.js
- my-component.udm.js
- my-component.udm.min.js

Now, for the `GitHub Page` publication, I'am building a page explaining the details and the features of the component. I'll use a `/docs` folder as root for the `GitHub Page` (I don't want to use a `gh-pages` branch).

For this, I have to build a basic `Vue` App without `Vue CLI`, `Webpack` or so.

The `index.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  ...
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <script src="js/my-component.umd.js"></script> 
  ...
  </head>

  <body>
    ...
    <div id="app">..</div>
    ...
    <script type="module">
      var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          message: 'Hello Vue!'
        },
        components: {
          myComponent: my-component   
        }
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Info: I copied `dist/my-component.umd.js` to the `docs/js` folder in order to have a standalone folder.*

The page works well if I do not use the component in the Vue script (Vue works properly). But, when I use the component, the page shows this error `(index):199 Uncaught ReferenceError: vue is not defined` which is pointing directly to `myComponent: my-component`.

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Is that a public github site? If so, please include the link.

Comment: Note that `my-component` is not a valid identifier per se; it's a binary expression `my - component`. Which will probably just give a ReferenceError. Try `window['my-component']`

Comment: @Paul The component is public on GitHub but not the page (yet). For reference, the GitHub link is https://github.com/yannmasoch/vue-image-alpha

Comment: @CMS I'll try `widnow['my-component']`

Comment: @CMS you were right about the name of the component. So there are 2 solutions: using `window['my-component']` or repackaging the component with a valid name such as `myComponent` - `myComponent.umd.js`. Please write you answer/solution down bellow and I'd validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the scripts in the body section before your app code. Otherwise, Vue library could be loaded after running your app code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  ...
  ...
  </head>

  <body>
    ...
    <div id="app">..</div>
    ...
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="js/my-component.umd.js"></script> 
    <script type="module">
      var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          message: 'Hello Vue!'
        },
        components: {
          myComponent: my-component   
        }
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like you said, I put the the scripts in the body but I still have the same error

Comment: Could you check if your code is referencing `Vue` as `vue` (lowercase) in some place of `my-component`?  (Because error message is `vue is not defined`)

Comment: Vue is working fine in fact, the issue was coming from the name of my component `my-component` which was not correct because of the `-`. So I repackaged the component with a correct name `myComponent` and everything works great now!